# Basic Database Design

Tags: database-design

This question would be a bit childish, I have three tables, users, usergroups and contacts.  In my system, the end user can create a contact and subsequently he\she may define the visibility of the contact by setting only for that user, or for a set of users or a set of usergroups.  So I am wondering, how my database design would be, it should be many to many between users and contacts or many to many between usergroups and contacts.  Definitely there is a one to many relationship between users and usergroups.

Thanks
Thurein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the possibility to set the visibility for a set of users or a set of usergroups then you need both m2m tables you mentioned. One contacts_users and one contacts_usergroups.

What I've said is true if "set of users" is different from a single "usergroup".

Comment: Yeah, how about this, there is a one to many relation between users and usergroups, and, I am only required to set the visibility to a set of usergroups.

Comment: Then you're fine with a single m2m table. You need the other one only if you want to set the visibility to a single user.

Comment: Wait a moment: one2many users-usergroups? Are you sure? Shouldn't it be m2m? Users have many Usergroups and Usergroups has many Users?

Comment: Yes, correct, m2m between users-usergroups. So, you also think, it is correct to have m2m relationship between usergroups and contacts, if I am dealing the visibility only with the use group?  So, the design would be m2m between contacts and usergroups, and another m2m between users and usergroups, right? :)

Comment: Yes, I think so if I understood correctly your problem. I mean to understand a relationship is pretty simple. Does the user hide the contact from many UserGroups and can't UserGroup see many contacts? If yes then it's a m2m. Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can accept my answer :)